# How does a new node register in the network?

Tags: nodes, network

I am just trying to get into the topic of Etherium and Blockchain and currently I do not understand the following.

Etherium network is decentralized p2p network. But if I start a node, the network must somehow recognize this new participant. How does a node register in the network or in other words how does my new node "C" know that there are nodes "A" and "B"? Is there somewhere a central place, a kind of node registry?